# How to use credential eg: Employee Social Security Number that is in login.cs to reflect in another form eg:expense.cs(Without manually typing))

Tags: c#, devexpress

This is the login page that has the credentials the user enters while logging in.

```cs
private void simpleButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        string myConnection = "datasource = localhost;database = imprest system;port = 3306;username = root;password = ''";
        MySqlConnection myConn = new MySqlConnection(myConnection);
        MySqlCommand SelectCommand = new MySqlCommand("select * from user where **employeeSSN = '" + employeeSSN_txt.Text + "'** and Password = '" + pass_txt.Text + "'", myConn);

        MySqlDataReader myreader;
        myConn.Open();
        myreader = SelectCommand.ExecuteReader();
        int count = 0;
        while (myreader.Read())
        {
            count = count + 1;
        }
        if (count == 1)
        {
            Dashboard dashboard = new Dashboard();
            dashboard.ShowDialog();
        }
        else if (count > 1)
        {
            XtraMessageBox.Show("Error logging in");
        }
        else
        {
            XtraMessageBox.Show("Incorrect Username and Password.Try Again");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        XtraMessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

The part of code where I would like to use the Employee social security Number without having to input it manually.

```cs
private void simpleButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string myConnection = "datasource = localhost;database = imprest system;port = 3306;username = root;password = ''";
    MySqlConnection myConn = new MySqlConnection(myConnection);
    MySqlCommand InsertCommand = new MySqlCommand("insert into expenseaccount where ExpenseType = '" + Expense_txt + "' and Amount = '" + Amount_txt + "' and **employeeSSN =** ", myConn);

    MySqlDataReader myreader;
    myConn.Open();
    myreader = InsertCommand.ExecuteReader();
}
```

Comment: If the user doesn't input their SSN manually where do you presume you would retrieve it from? Would this be stored on their machine, similar to login systems that remember your User ID? We need more information.

Comment: The system is designed in a way that you cannot login without your SSN...so once you log in,the system should use that SSN you provided on login to perform other queries

Comment: So why not store that value in a global static variable so that it can be used throughout the program? Or pass it between forms as required?